# Using PHP Variable as ID and calling from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Im using this is an ID

```
 $id = $row['id'];
 echo "<input type='text' id='$id' value='$row["s_code"]'>";
```

How can I get that ID in javascript function? I want it in here...

```
 var scode  = $('#').val();
```

While loop..

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlSimplex , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<input type='text' id='$id' value='".$row['s_code']."' readonly>";
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['description'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='comval'  value='$newProductID'>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<input type='text' size='7' id='userqtyval'>";
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo "<input type='button' onclick='addthis()'  value='Add!'>";
        echo "</td></tr>";  

    }
```

Javascript

```
  function addthis() {

            var myID = '$id';
            var scode = $("#"+myID).val();


            alert(scode);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'insertsimplextoc_comp.php',
                    data: { simplexcode: scode },
                }); 
    }
```

Been stuck on this for over a week!

Comment: That surely depends on the context, timing and other considerations of when and how you want to select exactly *that* element...!?

Comment: I done an alert(scode); and is comes out as undefined...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Whats the purpose. Please provide your scenario.

Comment: Maybe this way: `var scode  = $('#'+<?php echo $id; ?>).val();`

Comment: @vbrmnd I have a while loop outputting a html table with data from database. At the end of each row I have a button 'Add' which should allow the user to add this row to another table. But for each button it's value is displaying as the first id value in the table. So every value is displaying as the same.

Comment: @Wo0dSiiE please provide the code for that while loop in your question and it will help to see what might be wrong

Comment: Please show us where in your code you are executing your JavaScript.

Comment: @ultimater  function addthis() { 
        var scode = $("#"+myID).val();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlSimplex , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo "<input type='text' id='$id' value='".$row['s_code']."' readonly>";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['description'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='comval'  value='$newProductID'>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<input type='text' size='7' id='userqtyval'>";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<input type='button' class='submit-scode' data-field-id='$id' value='Add!'>";
    echo "</td></tr>";  
}
```

Javascript (using jQuery `click` event):

```
$('.submit-scode').click(function(){
    var field_id = $(this).attr('data-field-id');
    var scode = $("#"+field_id).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'insertsimplextoc_comp.php',
        data: { simplexcode: scode },
    }); 
});
```

Untested, but it should work.

Comment: Share some more of your script. You didn't say, that there were more than one record. ;-) Every time you create a record, the `myID` variable will be overwritten, thats why at the end you just have the latest record.

Comment: I've included the while loop in question now.

Comment: Okay, what do you want to the with the value? I'd recommend not relying on the `id` but using the DOM to do what you want to. It would help if you share the Javascript and explain what you want to do with it.

Comment: I want to post it to another php script and update an sql table..added the javascript

Comment: Why not just create a form for each table row with a submit button? You could even submit each form via jQuery, so that there is no reloading, but that seems much easier that doing it via Javascript...

Comment: I need it to be done dynamically because the page shouldn't refresh

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: i put in an alert(code); after var scode=$("#"+field_id).val(); and it didnt work :/

Comment: Sorry, mixed up Javascript and jQuery. Use `.attr()` instead of `.getAttr()`. Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add the id of the current loop as a parameter to the addthis function:

```
echo "<input type='button' onclick='addthis(\"$id\")'  value='Add!'>";
```

Then grab the id when the function is called like so:

```
function addthis(myID)
{
     var scode = $("#"+myID).val();
     //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have to keep track of that dynamic id's

It you have that id then you can do something like this

var id="assign php varable";

var scode =$('#'+id).val();

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want it to be used in the `addthis()` function ?

In this case, you'll hve to give a similar class to all your readonly `inputs`.

Then, while clicking on the add button, you'll have to check for its parent `<tr>`

I made some example here : http://jsfiddle.net/captain_torche/frzadnbb/

---

Or, you could alteratively put the ID as a parameter of the `addthis()` function, like so :

```
echo "<input type='button' onclick='addthis(".$id.")'  value='Add!'>";
```